# Changing the URLs posted to Facebook Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page, facebook-timeline

I have a Facebook page tab that uses the following function to post an action to the timeline after the user has completed a form.

```
function postFoo(){
    FB.api(
        '/me/<?php echo $namespace; ?>:foo?bar=<?php echo $url;?>',
        'post',
        function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                    console.log(response.error);
            } else {
                    console.log('Foo was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        });
}
```

This all works correctly and the action is added to the timeline correctly however the URls of the links contained in the timeline post like back to the apps actual location (e.g. http://foo.bar.com/app) rather than the facebook tab URL as one might expect. I have tried changing the redirect URI to the page tab address without any luck.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and if there are any resolutions or suggestions I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky. Facebook will always send the user back to the URL you've used in the object.

What you need to do is detect if the user is coming from Facebook and then redirect them back to the Fan Page. You can do this in PHP my checking if the URL has `fb_source` or `fb_action_ids` in it.

PHP Example:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['fb_source'] ) || isset( $_GET['fb_action_ids'] ) ) {
    header( 'Location: '. $fan_page_url );
}
?>
```

This will redirect anyone clicking on the action to bounce back to the Fan Page the action came from.